# implementing methods of traits with additional implicit parameters

Tags: scala, implicit, traits

I want an object to implement the trait `Iterable` and pass an additional implicit parameter to the implemented method:

```
object MyRepository extends Iterable[Something] {

  def iterator(implict entityManager: EntityManager): Iterator[Something] = ...

}
```

Obviously this doesn't work because the `iterator` method has no implicit parameter and is hence not implemented by the method shown above.

An example use case is the `map` method which I want to apply to the repository values:

```
   def get = Action {
     Transaction { implicit EntityManager => 
       val result = MyRepository.map(s => s ...)
     }
   }
```

Is there some way to implement the `Iterable` trait and capture the implicit pramameter?

Comment: I've tried very hard, but could not make sense of what you are saying. Care to reword your question?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: I've added an example and hope it shows my intention.

Comment: Oh, of course, I see. You want to implement `Iterable.iterator` but need an additional implicit parameter (in the implementation) which is obviously not defined in the original signature.

Comment: Add the implicit parameter to the class constructor implementing the `Iterable` trait (or create a factory method with an implicit parameter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that `Iterable.iterator` does not have this implicit in its signature, you cannot expect to be able to implement this method while adding this implicit: that would be another method (specifically, another overload).

However, if `MyRepository`was a class rather than an object, you could capture the implicit in the class constructor.
And if you want to keep the same use style (as in `MyRepository.map{ ... }` rather than `new MyRepository.map{ ... }`), what you can do is to provide an implicit conversion from the object to the class.

Here is an example:

```
object MyRepository {  
  class MyRepositoryIterable(implicit entityManager: EntityManager) extends Iterable[Something] {
    def iterator: Iterator[Something] = ???
  }
  implicit def toIterable(rep: MyRepository.type)(implicit entityManager: EntityManager): MyRepositoryIterable = new MyRepositoryIterable
}
```

What happens now when you do `MyRepository.map(...)` is that the object gets implicitly converted into an instance of `MyRepositoryIterable` which captures the implicit `EntityManager` value. The `MyRepositoryIterable` is the class that actually implements `Iterable`.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that I need to create a new Repository for each transaction?

Comment: No. `MyRepository` is still an object (and thus unique). Your example code (the `get` method) would work as is without any change, only now the call to `map` implcitly entails the creation of a `MyRepositoryIterable` instance (but this is transparent).